# List of variables used in python program

Tags: python, variables

How can we find all the variables in a python program???
for eg.
**Input**

```
def fact(i):
    f=2
    for j in range(2,i+1):
        f = f * i
        i = i - 1
    print 'The factorial of ',j,' is ',f
```

**Output**

Variables-- f,j,i

Comment: You're aware that you'll need much better-structured and fine-grained data (e.g. scoping information) to actually reason about the program? The dynamic features of Python make this impossible in general in any case though... Besides, how come `fact` doesn't count as a variable? It's a mutable, untyped binding just like `f`, `i` and `j`. Or do you simply want to extract only the local variable names from a single given function?

Comment: This is jus a sample program,,,in actual program can be of any type and of any length...
All i wnt to do is find all the variables used in that python program....

Comment: Why can't you read the source to find the assignment statements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get this information from functions:

```
>>> fact.func_code.co_varnames
('i', 'f', 'j')
```

Note these variables names will be generated only if the bytecode for them is built.

```
>>> def f():
        a = 1
        if 0:
            b = 2
>>> f.func_code.co_varnames
('a',)
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that the set of variable names is potentially infinite, due to `setattr` and some other dynamic programming techniques (such as `exec`). You can, however, perform simple static analysis with the [ast](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html) module:

```
import ast

prog = ("\ndef fact(i):\n    f=2\n    for j in range(2,i+1):\n        f = f*i\n"+
       "        i = i - 1\n    print 'The factorial of ',j,' is ',f")
res = set()
for anode in ast.walk(ast.parse(prog)):
    if type(anode).__name__ == 'Assign':
        res.update(t.id for t in anode.targets if type(t).__name__ == 'Name')
    elif type(anode).__name__ == 'For':
        if type(anode.target).__name__ == 'Name':
            res.add(anode.target.id)
print('All assignments: ' + str(res))
```

Answer (score 1):

Having answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7759344/724357) before, I'll paste the relevent bits here:

> For help finding things in the current namespace, check out the
>   [pprint library](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html), [the dir builtin](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir), [the locals builtin](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals),
>   [and the globals builtin](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#globals).

<strike>Please note that functions do not have any variables in existence until the actually run.</strike> See JBernardo's answer for getting to the variables within compiled functions. For example:

```
>>> def test():
...     i = 5
...
>>> locals()
{'argparse': <module 'argparse' from 'c:\python27\lib\argparse.pyc'>, '__builtins__': <module '
__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__package__': None, 'i': 5, 'test': <function test at 0x02C929F0>, '
__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
>>> dir(test)
['__call__', '__class__', '__closure__', '__code__', '__defaults__', '__delattr__', '__dict__',
 '__doc__', '__format__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__globals__', '__hash__', '__init__',
 '__module__', '__name__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'func_closure', 'func_code', 'func_defaults', 'fu
nc_dict', 'func_doc', 'func_globals', 'func_name']
>>>
```

See how the test function is located in the local namespace. I've called `dir()` on it to see interesting contents, and the `i` variable is not listed. Compare that to a class declaration and object creation:

```
>>> class test():
...     def __init__(self):
...          self.i = 5
...
>>> s = test()
>>> locals()
{'argparse': <module 'argparse' from 'c:\python27\lib\argparse.pyc'>, '__builtins__': <module '
__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__package__': None, 'i': 5, 's': <__main__.test instance at 0x02CE45
08>, 'test': <class __main__.test at 0x02C86F48>, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
>>> dir(s)
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'i']
>>>
```

Finally, notice how this does not say if these items are variables, constants, functions, or even classes declared inside the class! Use at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

`globals()` will return a dict of all the global variables.

`locals()` will return a dict of all local variables, e.g. all the variables in the scope it's called from.